# How can I extract all anchor tags, their hrefs and their anchor text within a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, domdocument

I need to process links within an html string in several different ways.

```
$str = 'My long <a href="http://example.com/abc" rel="link">string</a> has any
        <a href="/local/path" title="with attributes">number</a> of
        <a href="#anchor" data-attr="lots">links</a>.'
$links = extractLinks($str);
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $pattern = "#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie";
    if (preg_match($pattern,$str)) {
        // Process Remote links
        //   For example, replace url with short url,
        //   or replace long anchor text with truncated
    } else {
        // Process Local Links, Anchors

    }
}
function extractLinks($str) {
    // First, I tried DomDocument
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($str);
    return $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    // But this just returns:
    //   DOMNodeList Object
    //   (
    //       [length] => 3
    //   )

    // Then I tried Regex
    if(preg_match_all("|<a.*(?=href=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>|i", $str, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches);
    }
    // But this didn't work either.
}
```

Desired result of `extractLinks($str)`:

```
[0] => Array(
           'str' = '<a href="http://example.com/abc" rel="link">string</a>',
           'href' = 'http://example.com/abc';
           'anchorText' = 'string'
       ),
[1] => Array(
           'str' = '<a href="/local/path" title="with attributes">number</a>',
           'href' = '/local/path';
           'anchorText' = 'number'
       ),
[2] => Array(
           'str' = '<a href="#anchor" data-attr="lots">links</a>',
           'href' = '#anchor';
           'anchorText' = 'links'
       );
```

I need all of these so I can do things like edit the href (add tracking, shorten, etc.), or replace the whole tag with something else (`<a href="/u/username">username</a>` could become `username`).

Here's a [demo](https://eval.in/147831) of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The Pony, he comes! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: It's weird how many people *still* try and parse html with regex's

Comment: @Palpatim LOL! I feel like I stepped into S.O. lore right there.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use regular expression? I have another solution if using regular expression is not mandatory

Comment: Hint, not with regex!

Comment: `(<a href="([\w:/\.#]+)(.+)>([\w]+)</a>)` works with your example, but it would break if href wasn't the first attribute or href was not all lowercase. It would break in other ways, too, but it works for your example data. :-D

Comment: @Ryan in the regex you tried I don't think you want `.*` for the first group, I'd switch that to `[^>]*` as well.

Comment: @Ryan So I would suggest to use DomDocument and `$dom->loadHTML($str);` then you can easily search for all `<a>` and get any attribute of them if you want by `$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')`

Comment: @Javad, I tried that -- see my question above and the demo.  All I get is a `[length] => 3` response. What am I missing?

Comment: A ha! `Foreach` loops through it perfectly. But still can't get the href to show up: https://eval.in/147835

Comment: You might also want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: Got it, I'm on the right track now: `->getAttribute('href');`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to change it as:

```
$str = 'My long <a href="http://example.com/abc" rel="link">string</a> has any
    <a href="/local/path" title="with attributes">number</a> of
    <a href="#anchor" data-attr="lots">links</a>.';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$output = array();
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item) {
   $output[] = array (
      'str' => $dom->saveHTML($item),
      'href' => $item->getAttribute('href'),
      'anchorText' => $item->nodeValue
   );
}
```

By putting it in a loop and using `getAttribute`, `nodeValue` and `saveHTML(THE_NODE)` you will have your output

Comment: @Ryan I updated my answer, it should be `$dom->saveHTML($item)` not `$item->saveHTML($item)`

Comment: this won't work if you have a special character in that HTML string i.e. &

Answer (score 6):

Like this

```
<a\s*href="([^"]+)"[^>]+>([^<]+)</a>
```

1. The overall match is what you want for 0 array element
2. Group#1 capture is what you want for 1 array element
3. Group#2 capture is what you want for 2 array element

Use `preg_match($pattern,$string,$m)`

The array elements will be in `$m[0]` `$m[1]` `$m[3]`

[Working PHP demo here](http://ideone.com/A59IpP)

```
$string = 'My long <a href="http://example.com/abc" rel="link">string</a> has any
        <a href="/local/path" title="with attributes">number</a> of
        <a href="#anchor" data-attr="lots">links</a>. ';
$regex='|<a\s*href="([^"]+)"[^>]+>([^<]+)</a>|';
$howmany = preg_match_all($regex,$string,$res,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @GordonM `<a` tag is self contained. This regex will not eat other tags.

Comment: because regex is a really brittle solution at best.

Comment: @Ryan please see full PHP demo added in my question http://ideone.com/A59IpP

Comment: It will match strings in comments and cdata (javascript)

Comment: @HansSchindler Why somebody downvoted your answer with "working regex"? It's simple. Besides of [diks are here](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) your regex doen't work for me. This works: `'#\<a href="([^"]*)".*?\>(.+?)\<\/a\>#s'`. Please update your answer.